# c# selenium hide Internet Explorer browser window

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium with c# and I would like to hide the internet explorer browser window. As far as I understood IE does not support headless browser.

For the particular case I'm working on, IE is the fastest browser, since I'm accessing internal company webpage.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Use trifle. http://triflejs.org

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'm happy to help you out.
I am still looking for a solution to start IE headless but with the minimized version I could also help myself.

here an idea:

```
IWebDriver webDriver;

public void StackTest()
{
   webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   webDriver.Manage().Window.Minimize();
}
```

as a little tip I recommend to keep IE waiting until everything is loaded:

```
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```